# to get response using curlpp

Tags: c++, curlpp

I am using curlpp to receive the response. I am referring this example of curlpp site http://curlpp.org/index.php/examples/64-example-14.
But I am not getting where the response is stored so that I can use it for further purpose.
The code is only showing the integer values of status of the request.
I have gone through google also but not able to figure it out.

```
curlpp::Multi::Msgs msgs = requests.info();

for (curlpp::Multi::Msgs::iterator pos = msgs.begin(); pos != msgs.end(); pos++) 
{
    if (pos->second.msg == CURLMSG_DONE)
    {
        /* Find out which handle this message is about */
        if (pos->first == &request1)
        {
            printf("First request completed with status %d\n", pos->second.code);
        }
        else if (pos->first == &request2) 
        {
            printf("Second request completed with status %d\n", pos->second.code);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I edited the Q to make it more readable and you broke it again? Grrr!

Comment: @Als I fixed it, waiting for someone to accept edit.

Comment: @Keoki Zee: I know you did and all in good spirit of SO, But I already had done it and the OP broke it again, which you had to fixed..And i didn't accept your edit because We can't keep doing this recursively, let the OP fix it!

Answer (score 6):

You can specify other streams with the option WriteStream:

```
std::stringstream result;

request.setOpt(cURLpp::Options::WriteStream(&result));
request.perform();
```

Comment: Thank you. `std::ostringstream result` works too, I've found.

Answer (score 1):

Read the previous examples, by default when you say perform it goes to the stdout or you can specify other streams.

From the same site, different example http://curlpp.org/index.php/examples/48-example-01

```
myRequest.perform();
os << myRequest;
```

Where os is a custom output stream

so for two streams like this example add something like

```
os1 << request1;
os2 << request2;
```

to get both the responses